# Creating a trigger to copy data from 1 table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that will copy data from table 1 when and paste it into table 2, when a new entry has been put into table 1:

```
Table 1  

id | first_name | last_name | email | uid | pwd 
----+------------+-----------+-------+-----+-----


Table 2 

user_id | user_first_name | user_last_name | user_uid 
---------+-----------------+----------------+---------
```

the code i am using is this :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS usersetup_identifier ON users;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usersetup_identifier_insert_update() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    if NEW.identifier is null then
        NEW.identifier := "INSERT INTO users_setup (user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_uid)
                          SELECT id, first_name, last_name, uid 
                          FROM users";
    end if;
RETURN NEW;
end
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER usersetup_identifier
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE usersetup_identifier_insert_update();
```

but when i insert data into table 1 i am getting this error message :

```
NOTICE:  identifier "INSERT INTO users_setup (user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_uid)
                          SELECT id, first_name, last_name, uid 
                          FROM users" will be truncated to "INSERT INTO users_setup (user_id, user_first_name, user_last_na"
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "identifier"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT NEW.identifier is null"
PL/pgSQL function usersetup_identifier_insert_update() line 3 at IF
```

the table descriptions are:

```
                                     Table "public.users"
       Column   |     Type      | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
    ------------+---------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
     id         | integer       |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
     first_name | character(20) |           | not null | 
     last_name  | character(20) |           | not null | 
     email      | character(60) |           | not null | 
     uid        | character(20) |           | not null | 
     pwd        | character(20) |           | not null | 
    Indexes:
        "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
        "users_email_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
        "users_pwd_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (pwd)
        "users_uid_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (uid)
    Triggers:
        usersetup_identifier AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE usersetup_identifier_insert_update()
```

All the columns match there corresponding columns
can any one help and tell me where i am going wrong?

```
                                            Table "public.users_setup"
         Column      |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 
    -----------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
     id              | integer                |           | not null | nextval('users_setup_id_seq'::regclass)
     user_id         | integer                |           |          | 
     user_first_name | character(20)          |           |          | 
     user_last_name  | character(20)          |           |          | 
     user_uid        | character(20)          |           |          |
```

Can any one help me with where I am going wrong?

Comment: users table definition please. also how did you want to use "new.identifier"?..

Comment: Why are you assigning a new value to `new.identifier` if you actually want to _run_ an insert statement? Additionally: double quotes are for identifiers. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes `"foo"` is a name (e.g. a table name), `'foo'` is  character constant

Comment: There is no column `identifier` in any of those two tables.

Comment: I am new to this so still learning i put new identifier on as this was in a example i found. if i don't need this how would i write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code

1. the table `users` has a column named `identifier` so the expression `NEW.identifier` is invalid
2. You are assigning a value to a (non-existing) column with the expression `new.identifier := ...` - but you want to run an INSERT statement, not assign a value.
3. String values need to be enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `'Arthur'`, double quotes denote identifiers (e.g. a table or column name). But there is no column named `"INSERT INTO use ..."`

To access the values of the row being inserted you need to use the `new` record and the column names. No need to *select* from the table:

As far as I can tell, this is what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usersetup_identifier_insert_update() 
   RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users_setup (user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_uid)
    values (new.id, new.first_name, new.last_name, new.uid);
    RETURN NEW;
end
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

Unrelated, but:

copying data around like that is bad database design. What happens if you change the user's name? Then you would need to `UPDATE` the `user_setup` table as well. It is better to only store a (foreign key) reference in the `user_setup` table that references the `users` table.

Comment: Thank you that does what i need at the moment as the user name will not be changed, but i will look into doing a foreign key if this changes.